# How to create a empty folder with QuaZIP

Tags: qt, quazip

I've successfully created folders and files inside a ZIP file with QuaZIP, but to create a folder i used a not elegant way, that creates a file without name inside the ZIP file. Is there any way to create empty folders inside a ZIP file without create a file inside that folder?

Code to create folder:

```
QuaZip zip("path_to\\zipFile.zip");
zip.open(QuaZip::mdCreate);
QuaZipFile outFile(&zip);
outFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly, QuaZipNewInfo("SomeFolder\\"));
outFile.close();
```